# Does the Euclidean Algorithm always find the minimum a,b?

Tags: euclidean-algorithm

A Euclidean algorithm takes any two integers m,n and finds $$d=\gcd(m,n)$$ It also finds integers $a,b$ such that $$am+bn=d$$

Q: Does the Euclidean Algorithm always find the minimum $a,b$? That is, is it possible for

$$\exists a^\prime,b^\prime \in Z \ni a^\prime m+b^\prime n=d, \\
\left \lVert a' \right \rVert+ \left \lVert b' \right \rVert <
\left \lVert a \right \rVert+ \left \lVert b \right \rVert $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The identity that you are referring to, $$am + bn = d$$ Is knows as [Bezout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity)

If we know one pair of Beout's coeffiecients $(a, b)$, then the others  $(a', b')$ are in general of the form

$$
a' = a + \frac{kn}{d} \\
b' = b - \frac{km}{d} \\
\text{where} \ k\in \mathbb{Z}
$$

Let's check that $a', b'$ actually satisfy the identity:

$$
a'm + b'n = \left(a + \frac{kn}{d}\right)m + \left(b - \frac{km}{d} \right)n \\
= am + \frac{kmn}{d} +bn -\frac{kmn}{d} \\
= am + bn \\
= d
$$

Cool, it looks like they do. Hence,

$$
a'm + b'n = d \ \ \ \forall a', b'
$$

However, notice that

$$
\left|a' \right|  + \left|b'\right| =  \left| a + \frac{kn}{d}\right| + \left| b -\frac{km}{d} \right| \\
= |a| + |b| + \left|k \left[ \frac{n}{d} - \frac{m}{d} \right] \right|, k \in \mathbb{Z}
$$

Since

$$
\left(\delta = \left|k \left[ \frac{n}{d} - \frac{m}{d} \right] \right| \right) >= 0,
$$

$$a' + b' \geq a + b$$

and is equal when $\delta = 0$

Comment: This is great thanks! I have been looking for the Bezout's identity!

Comment: Can you explain the bottom section a bit more? The part after "However, notice".

Comment: There is no justification provided for that penultimate step.  Expressions cannot generally be moved outside the absolute value bars, except that the triangle inequality gives us that, an inequality but not equality.